# passing two parameters to println in java

Tags: java, methods, println

```
public void showOver(char x, int v){ System.out.println(x,v); } }
```

---

I have try to pass x and v to "Println" like above and I've got an error

why?

Comment: Because `PrintStream.println` only accepts a single parameter. Join them together somehow, e.g. add them, or concatenate them into a string.

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.println()` only takes a single argument. You need to concatenate x and v somehow into a single String.

Multiple solutions, the easiest

```
System.out.println(x + ", " + v);
```

others might include

```
System.out.println(String.format("%c, %d", x, v));
```

You can also use `System.out.printf()`, but note this does not include a newline, so you'll need to add

```
System.out.printf("%c, %d\n", x, v);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("%c, %d", x, v)
```